# Where to find replacement Clarks Skeletal right brake?

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake, brake-levers

I had completely fixed a stuck piston, when I bloody managed to perfectly snap a reservoir screw so I have no chance of removing it. I’ve had a look online, but I can’t find anywhere selling either the right (front) brake whatever you’d call the whole lever + reservoir bit that attaches to the handle bar, or a the whole new lever + calliper. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Sheared off bolts can be removed by drilling them out with some care. What's the diameter of the bolt?

Comment: Any replacement brake will do - any reason it has to be that exact brake.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Unfortunately, the question as it is formulated now is kinda offtopic here — we do not even know where you live to suggest a store for you to visit. And even if we knew and someone could suggest one, the answer would not be long-term useful to anyone else as stores open and close.

Comment: As it stands this is a shopping question.  If you wanted to try removing the snapped off bolt then it becomes on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

If you’re struggling to find a replacement part online, others would probably be googling the same terms and struggle too.

What you might not appreciate about your local bike shop is that shops generally have access to the majority of cycling brands through their various suppliers, even if you don’t see that brand on their shelves. It would be pretty trivial for a good shop to order something in if they can get it.

If they can’t find an exact replacement they might be able to show the current range and spot a compatible replacement lever.

You could also replace the whole brake for a different model as alluded to by mattnz, or have a go at drilling out the screw if it’s otherwise junk - might be prohibitively small!

Comment: A local bike shop might connect you with a machine shop which could remove the screw.